# Cant Open Android Emulator in Visual Studio Code Getting Error , Can't Find Any Fix

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, windows-10, android-emulator

Recently Formatted My Laptop , Previously the Android Emulator Was Working Great in My VS-Code. Now after fresh install of my `VS Code`, I installed the flutter and dart plugin . And created a sample flutter project to text my Android Emulator . To run the emulator I used the flutter run command but it showed only chrome and explorer . So I installed the Android iOS Plugin available in the `VS Code`. But When I Run The Emulator I am getting errors And The Emulator is not starting .But The emulator works great in Android Studio . I am attaching the photo of the error which I see in The VS-Code popup. I also added the Android SDK to my environment variables. Please have a look to the vs code errors and the environment Variables. I am really frustrated now. Wasted my 2 hrs but no solution.

Error while opening the emulator in `VS code`
[image: ERROR WHILE OPENING THE EMULATOR IN VS CODE CLICK TO SEE THE PICTURE]

Environment Variables:
[image: ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES]

`flutter` doctor and `flutter` emulator results:
[image: FLUTTER DOCTOR AND FLUTTER EMULATOR RESULTS CLICK TO SEE]

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor` on terminal and insert in question?. If you find everything is ok, type `flutter emulators` on terminal.

Comment: I have edited my questions and added the flutter doctor and flutter emulator results. My Emulator details shows when I type the command flutter emulator but still it is not running in the vs-code

Comment: on terminal run `flutter run --emulator launch Pixel_4_XL_API_30`, check if it works. i think you can reinstall Vscode plugins for easy solution.

Comment: flutter run --emulator launch Pixel_4_XL_API_30 yes this command works but i have to type this command every time . My plugin was working fine but now its not . Reinstalled the plugin also but not fixed

Comment: click on debug icon , and edit run profile.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you'd need to add absolute directories `\emulator` and `\platform-tools` into `Path`

... just double-click the one `Path` at the bottom of your screenshot, in order to do so.

Comment: Done , but still not working I added both \emulator and \platform-tools in the bottm path as well as above path , But still not working I am really frustated by this issue now..

Comment: I just figured out that the extension is not working for me , but when I press the F5 button VS-CODE asks for the android emulator pixel . I think I am satisfied with this now . Thats buddy because I think your answer fixed this because earlier i pressed F5 Vs-Code only showed chrome and edge. Thanks Again